# Create new vector from others, using only duplicates

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Let's say I have a set of `vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> a = {2,3,8,4,9,0,6,10,5,7,1};
std::vector<int> b = {6,10,8,2,4,0};
std::vector<int> c = {0,1,2,4,5,8};
```

I want to create a new vector, in such a way that only elements which are common to all input vectors are input into the new vector as follows:

```
std::vector<int> abc = {8,2,0,8}; // possible output, order doesn't matter
```

I have seen many questions asking for how to remove duplicates, but I wish to retain ***only*** duplicates.

Is there an existing efficient STL algorithm or construct that will do this for me, or do I need to write my own?

Comment: So you want something like a [set intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?

Comment: No they are not sorted in any meaningful way, but each element will be unique in each vector, e.g. 4 will only appear once in each one.

Comment: set_intersection only when elements are sorted.

Comment: You can insert all of them into an `std::map<int,int>` instance, then iterate the [key,value] pairs of the map, and for each pair, add the key to the output array if the value is equal to the number of input vectors.

Comment: @goodvibration I guess you mean the value equal to the number of vectors

Comment: @dWinder: Just changed it :)

Comment: @goodvibration That sounds like an answer...

Comment: Could you please go into more detail in an answer?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify (as in, sort) the input vectors?

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Comparing with a `map` solution, that would take a lot more coding, equal time complexity (at best), and worse space complexity.

Comment: @YSC OP said in a comment: "but each element will be unique in each vector"

Comment: @YSC: If this dude is looking for duplicates in general, then he/she can replace "equal to the number of input vectors" with "larger than one". I believe that he or she is looking for duplicates presenting in **all** vectors.

Comment: my bad. @OP you should [edit] your answer to add that kind of info.

Comment: Your last edit should have been another question. It invalidates the answer below.

Comment: Indeed. I will raise another question then.

Comment: The question has been rolled back, and another asked, which is my actual use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use an algorithm [set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)  to do this:
But you will also have to sort the `vector`s first

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> b = {0,2,4,6,8,10};
    std::vector<int> c = {0,1,2,4,5,8};

    std::vector<int> temp;
    std::vector<int> abc;

    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());

    std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(),
                          b.begin(), b.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(temp));

    std::set_intersection(temp.begin(), temp.end(),
                          c.begin(), c.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(abc));

    for(int n : abc)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1eXpX7uy4AIf4aFX)

Comment: @IanYoung 1. Changing the question substantially after an answer has been posted is not ok. 2. The answer still applies just the same for `std::pair` as for `int`. Nothing in this answer is specific to `int`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I agree with your comment but 1. he is not using `std::pair` and 2.`Pair` is not sortable.

Comment: @Timo Oops, my bad.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, understood. Apologies.

Comment: @goodvibration you just have to be brave enough to survive the first wave. I mean who cares if the first vote was a "down" when the answer actually is helpful and gets votes accordingly on the long run

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Possibly, but having too many smart&$$es all in one place has to take its toll in the long run as well.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: Agree very much. The only thing is that people will think that there is something wrong with the post when they see `-1` and even if they don't downvote further, they will just ignore it. But there are some good souls who actually take time to read the post and vote on its merits.